# How to run code after ruby Kernel.exec

Tags: ruby, shell, unix

I have the following ruby shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$stdin.each_line do |line|
  pid = fork{
    exec line
    puts "after exec -> #{Process.pid}"
  }
  Process.wait pid
end
```

The `puts` method after `exec` is never executed. Based on `ri Kernel.exec`, it seems that `exec` replaces the current process by running the given external. So, it's supposed to replace the new forked processes with the external processes. How am I supposed to run anything after `exec` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You cannot.

Per the documentation for [`Kernel#exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec), "[it] replaces the current process by running the given external command".  That means that you are no longer running *your* code but instead the code you specified by the command.

If you want to "wrap" a system call then you should use [`Kernel#system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) (or the [backtick operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60)) to execute the command in a *subshell*.

Comment: In other words, don't pull the ripcord if you're not done. Also, `system` is preferable to the backticks style as it makes it abundantly clear what you're doing.

Comment: But is there any workaround for this? what if I want to run some external command and then modify the results? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As context, this is actually central to the way the Unix process model works. There *is* no primitive call that starts a new process with a different program. Instead, a process `fork`s itself into two copies of the same program, and one of them `exec`s, turning into the new program. When it forks, it can set up a line of communication (a pipe) between the parent and child. That's what the backtick operator does for you: builds a pipe, `fork`s, and `exec`s.